# NuGet nuspec dependency - how to include a private NuGet gallery

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package, nuspec

**Fixed - see Sara Lui's link to document in comments.**

I have created several NuGet packages which are available on our private Corporate NuGet gallery.

Several of these packages are dependent upon one common package.

However, when I add this to my Nuspec file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    ...
    <dependencies>
      <dependency id="MyCommonPackage" version="1.0">
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

Then it fails to install because it can't find "MyCommonPackage" - it's not looking for it in our corporate gallery:

> NotFound
>   https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/MyCommonPackage/index.json
>
> NotFound
>   https://dotnetmyget.blob.core.windows.net/artifacts/roslyn/nuget/v3/flatcontainer/MyCommonPackage/index.json

Visual Studio has this gallery referenced, but I suspect I need to reference it in the nuspec file (just not seeing how to do this).

Comment: I don't feel your problem. You see your package in Visual Studio hosted in your private gallery, but you don't see MyCommonPackage hosted in the same gallery? How are you trying to install this package? Maybe show us some print screens from Visual Studio with your configuration.

Comment: @Peska So Peska, I create a NuGet package called "MyCommonPackage" and put it on our corporate gallery.  I then create a second NuGet package called "MyReferencingPackage" which has "MyCommonPackage" as its dependency and also put that on our corporate gallery.  I then create a new Application in Visual Studio and try adding the NuGet package "MyReferencingPackage".  Installation fails for "MyReferencingPackage" as the installation process needs to find and install "MyCommonPackage" (but it's not looking at the right gallery).

Comment: @DrGriff, if you direct add the package 'MyCommonPackage', does this issue persists or not? Please go to Tools-Options-NuGet Package Manager and make sure your corporate gallery be added into the available package sources and checked.

Comment: @Sara Lui If I directly add both NuGet packages to the solution then it works fine, but what I don't want to do is to give other people a big list of NuGet packages to add, just the "top" one

Comment: @DrGriff, thanks for your update, how did you create the 'MyReferencingPackage', please check this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package and make sure the required file 'MyCommonPackage' is under the folder structure before we run the nuget pack command to generate the .nupkg file.

Comment: @Sara Lui I had followed that article, so I rechecked it and everything was in order.  So, starting from the top, I removed the package references, deleted the folders from the NuGet gallery and then re-published them from the bottom-up.  This time it just worked like a dream (with no changes apart from re-publishing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by [referring to link provided by @Sara Lui:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55870293/nuget-nuspec-dependency-how-to-include-a-private-nuget-gallery/55933915#comment98481463_55870293)

> please check this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package and make sure the required file 'MyCommonPackage' is under the folder structure before we run the nuget pack command to generate the .nupkg file.

I removed the package references, deleted the folders from the NuGet gallery and then re-published them from the bottom-up.  This time it just worked like a dream (with no changes apart from re-publishing).